# Is there any way to write to a pre-existing text file in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a txt file that I need to write to. I know that I can't write to this using File IO, so is there any way to write to this file?

Comment: Didn't this work? https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future<File> writeCounter(int counter) async {
  final file = await  File('your_path.txt');
  // Write the file
  return file.writeAsString('$counter');
}
```

and import the following packages

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

Comment: 'your_path' not always work. It throws `FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'dir' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)`

Comment: why `await` on File()? That is not a async method IMHO

Answer (score 16):

If you want to open the file in append mode you have to pass the file mode in your `writeAsString()` function else it will over write the file.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<File> writeCounter(int counter) async {
final file = await  File('your_path.txt');

  // Write the file
  return file.writeAsString('$counter',mode: FileMode.append);
 }
}
```